# Can I write to and read from a process in the same asyncio loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-asyncio

I have a process that reads input and writes output, like this *doubler*:

<sub>*(in reality it's actually a black box and the input and the output are completely independent)*</sub>

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r i; do
    sleep 0.$RANDOM
    echo $((i*2))
done
```

and a few functions in my Python code that feeds this process asynchronously:

```
import asyncio
import subprocess
import random

class Feeder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(['doubler.sh'],
                                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

    def feed(self, value):
        self.process.stdin.write(str(value).encode() + b'\n')
        self.process.stdin.flush()

feeder = Feeder()

async def feed_random():
    while True:
        feeder.feed(random.randint(0, 100))
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def feed_tens():
    while True:
        feeder.feed(10)
        await asyncio.sleep(3.14)

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(
        feed_random(),
        feed_tens(),
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

This works well. But I would like to read the output of the process too, like this:

```
...
stdout=subprocess.PIPE
...
for line in feeder.process.stdout:
    print("The answer is " + line.decode())
```

but that is blocking, so the feeding won't happen. Can this be done in the same *asyncio* loop? Or do I need another thread?

Comment: do you want everything to print? or just what ends up in `process.stdout`

Comment: @gold_cy *stdout* is sufficient, I don't need *stderr*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. In order to read from `stdout` asynchronously you have to switch to `asyncio.subprocess`.

```
import asyncio
import random

class Feeder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.process = None

    async def start_process(self):
        self.process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec('./doubler.sh',
            stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)

    async def feed(self, value):
        self.process.stdin.write(str(value).encode() + b'\n')
        await self.process.stdin.drain()

feeder = Feeder()

async def feed_random():
    while True:
        asyncio.ensure_future(feeder.feed(random.randint(0, 100)))
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def feed_tens():
    while True:
        asyncio.ensure_future(feeder.feed(10))
        await asyncio.sleep(3.14)

async def read_feed():
    while True:
        line = await feeder.process.stdout.readline()
        print("The answer is " + line.decode('utf-8'))


async def main():
    await feeder.start_process()
    await asyncio.gather(
        feed_random(),
        feed_tens(),
        read_feed()
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Interesting. Could you please explain what is *drain* for and why you use *ensure_future* instead of awaiting?

Comment: sure so `drain` is the equivalent of `flush`. then we use `ensure_future` to create an `asyncio.Task` for both feeding in a random integer and 10. if we use `await` that would be a blocking call until it completes. by creating a `Task` from each of them we can then have both tasks run _concurrently_ in our `asyncio.gather` call. hope that makes sense. if you are using `Python 3.7+` you can replace `ensure_future` with `asyncio.create_task` however, I wasn't sure what version you are using and `ensure_future` is backwards compatible.